# Multiple connections to the same sql warehouse with different credentials using the same user

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

So basically I have the following scenario: I have a CICD pipeline (using a Service Principal credentials) that is responsible for deploying power bi files from multiples teams in multiples workspaces. All datasets from all teams share the same SQL Warehouse in Databricks. This means that the process is creating only one connection to Databricks.
My issue is that these datasets came from different databases, each of these databases have dedicated a service user that only has access to that specific database. So one dataset can only be connected to a single database. My plan is creating one token per service user and use this token in the datasource connection in power bi. So basically each dataset could have a dedicated connection but because I'm using a single user to deploy everything if I update the connection for a new dataset, it will update for all dataset that already exists in power bi.

TL;DR is there a way of setting different credentials (multiple connections) to the same SQL Warehouse in the same Power BI account for a single user?

I try to create multiple connections in power bi but it only allows me to use them in Kudos or in Data Pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way of setting different credentials (multiple connections) to the same SQL Warehouse in the same Power BI account for a single user?

Today the only way is to use a Gateway.  Gateway connections have names, and support multiple separate connections to a single data source.

The other current solution is to use multiple service principals for deployment so each gets its own connection.

The feature you are looking for is called
Sharable Cloud Connections, and it's on the roadmap.